# Friendly_ID Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-id

The URL still shows the id and not the title even after using slug. 
Code as follows

**index.html.erb**

```
<title>Blog!</title>
<h1>List of the Posts</h1>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= link_to post.title,:id => post.slug%>
  <p><%= post.content %></p>
  <%= link_to "Edit",edit_post_path(post) %> |
  <%= link_to "Delete",post,:confirm=>"Are you sure ?",:method=>:delete %>
  <hr />
<% end %>
<p><%= link_to "Add a New Post",new_post_path %></p>
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts=Post.all
  end

  def show
    @posts=Post.find(params[:id])
  end
```

end

**Post Model**

```
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title,use: :slugged

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    new_record
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  get "blog/posts"
  resources :posts
end
```

I would want the link to be '**localhost:8080/posts/this+is+the+title**' and not '**localhost:8080/posts/2**'

Comment: Is it the bad formatting or are you doing `extend` et al in your controller?

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with this issue too.  When I linked to the show action of my resource, I would get the `id` in the url instead of my slug.  Although I could type in the slugged url and it would also work fine (I just couldn't link to the slugged url).  It turns out that I had to use named route helpers for friendly_id to display the slug in the url (I was using the old-school `controller: 'posts', action: 'show', id: post.id` in my `link_to` helper).  In your case, I would try changing:

```
<%= link_to post.title, :id => post.slug %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %>
```

Also, friendly_id version 5.0 requires that you change `Model.find` to `Model.friendly.find` in your controller (unless you explicitly override it `config/initializers/friendly_id.rb`.  Since this is an older post,  it might not apply to you, but I thought I'd add it anyway.  Try changing:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

to

```
def show
  @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Having this same issue...the slugs work if you enter them manually, but if you click a link the id still shows up.