# Friendly_id not showing up on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi guys im creating blog with friendly id, but its not working..

The problem is when i tried to edit the title, friendly id came up, but when i reopen, it just show the blog id. not the slug anymore

this is the code

in my model :

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
    
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

    def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
      slug.blank? || title_changed?
    end

end
```

my blog controller

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_blog, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
        @blogs = Blog.all
  end

  def show
    @blog = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @blog = Blog.new
  end

  def create
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)

    if @blog.save
        redirect_to blog_path(@blog), notice: "Successfully Created"
    else
        render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @blog.update(blog_params)
    redirect_to blog_path(@blog), notice: "Successfully Update"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @blog.destroy
    redirect_to blog_path(@blog)
  end

  private

    def set_blog
      @blog = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id])
      
    end

  def blog_params
    params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :body, :image, :category_id)
  end

end
```

i spent so much time to solve this.. please help

Comment: when you open the blog from index page it is also without friendly id? or only after update action?

Comment: yes, when i open it from index, it give me http://localhost:3000/blogs/4

Comment: but when i edited this, it show http://localhost:3000/blogs/slug

Comment: check this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/26087311/5841310